# Change the CSS for just one <a> tag

Tags: html, css, background-color

I have 3 links at the top of my webpage and a link embedded into an image.Those 3 have a different background color from the nav but, unfortunately, it also adds this to the image with the link. How do I take it off the image?

```css
html{
 font-family: abel;
 background-color: #a4bdd1;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}
body{
    overflow-x:hidden;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
nav {
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #e4e6e5;
/*    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
   left: 0;
   z-index: 9999;*/
  width: 100%;
   border-bottom: solid #05182e 2px;
   margin-top: -1px
}
nav li {
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 35px;
    padding: 15px;
    font-weight: bold;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

nav a{
 border-radius: 10%;
 padding: 8px;
 background-color: #cccccc;
 color: #1f3b5a;
 text-decoration: none;
 font-size: 30px;
 transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
nav a:hover{
 font-size: 40px;
 transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
nav img{
 width: 30%;
 border: none;
 transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
nav img:hover{
 width: 40%;
 transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
ul {
   margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
 <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Abel' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
 <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Bitter:700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
 <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicon-32x32.png" sizes="32x32" />
 <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicon-16x16.png" sizes="16x16" />
 <title>Brampton Thunder</title>
</head>

<body>

 <nav> 
     <ul> 
      <li><img src="images/logo.png" alt="Canadian Women's Hockey League Logo"></li>
         <li> <a href="index.html" target="_blank">Home</a></li>
         <li> <a href="roster.html" target="_blank">Roster</a></li>
         <li> <a href="schedule.html" target="_blank">Schedule</a></li>
         <li><a href="http://cwhl.ca" target="_blank"><img src="images/cwhllogo.png"></a></li>

     </ul>
 </nav>
```

Comment: Yay go Brampton! Anyways, just add id for that <a>  tag and then add CSS properties for it!

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
nav ul li:last-child a {
  background-color:#e4e6e5; 
}
```

Check snippet below

```css
html {
  font-family: abel;
  background-color: #a4bdd1;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
body {
  overflow-x: hidden;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
nav {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #e4e6e5;
  /*    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
   left: 0;
   z-index: 9999;*/
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom: solid #05182e 2px;
  margin-top: -1px
}
nav li {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 35px;
  padding: 15px;
  font-weight: bold;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
nav a {
  border-radius: 10%;
  padding: 8px;
  background-color: #cccccc;
  color: #1f3b5a;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 30px;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
nav ul li:last-child a {
  background-color: #e4e6e5;
}
nav a:hover {
  font-size: 40px;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
nav img {
  width: 30%;
  border: none;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
nav img:hover {
  width: 40%;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
ul {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <img src="images/logo.png" alt="Canadian Women's Hockey League Logo">
    </li>
    <li> <a href="index.html" target="_blank">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li> <a href="roster.html" target="_blank">Roster</a>
    </li>
    <li> <a href="schedule.html" target="_blank">Schedule</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="http://cwhl.ca" target="_blank">
        <img src="images/cwhllogo.png">
      </a>
    </li>

  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Only if only his last `li` is the image link.

Answer (score 0):

**html**

```
<li><a href="http://cwhl.ca" target="_blank" class="link"><img src="images/cwhllogo.png"></a></li>
```

**CSS**

```
.link { //whatever you want the link to look like }

.link:hover { //whatever you want the link to look like while being hovered on }
```

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is give all `<a>` tags that need a background a class. That way you just need to write like so:

```
nav a.bg {
    /* enter style here */
}
```

and like so in HTML:

```
<nav>
    <li><a href="#" class="bg">Link 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="bg">Link 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><img src="#"></a></li>
</nav>
```

**Alternatively**

Specify a background for all `nav a`, just like you did in the example. Then add a separate class to all `nav a` that contains an image, removing the background.

You could do it like so:

CSS:

```
nav a {
    background: #333;
}

nav a.img {
    background: transparent;
}
```

HTML:

```
<nav>
    <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="img"><img src="#"></a></li>
</nav>
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to give ONE link an id or class rather than TEN links?

Comment: Well it completely depends on the way you code. But sure, you would save some characters by doing like you said.

Comment: And time, if you had 1000 links and only one image link.

Comment: Time, you mean if you were to write every line of HTML manually? Well, then you should look up the term CMS. But yeah, I get your point.

Comment: By the way, all of this depends on the ratio between links and links with images. Imagine 1 000 links where 999 are image links. Well, you never know.

Answer (score 0):

You can give the `<a>` with the `<img>` an `id`:

```
<a id="image"><img /></a>
```

Then, you can set its background-color as nothing:

```
a#image {
  background-color: transparent;
}
```

Snippet:

```css
a {
  background-color: blue;
}
a#image {
  background-color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">abc</a>
<a href="#" id="image"><img src="//google.com/favicon.ico"></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of removing it, use a little CSS and javascript to disable it. First you'll want to remove the transition that takes place when the anchor or image is rolled over (and get rid of the gray button behind the image):

```
nav li:last-of-type a:hover, 
nav li:last-of-type a,
nav li:last-of-type a img{
    font-size:0;
    background:none;
    transition:none;
    width:30%;
    cursor:default;
}
```

Then use a little jQuery to prevent the link from working:

```
$('nav li:last-of-type a').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Full code and example:

```js
$('nav li:last-of-type a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

```css
html {
    font-family: abel;
    background-color: #a4bdd1;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body {
    overflow-x: hidden;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

nav {
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #e4e6e5;
    /*    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
   left: 0;
   z-index: 9999;*/
    width: 100%;
    border-bottom: solid #05182e 2px;
    margin-top: -1px
}

nav li {
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 35px;
    padding: 15px;
    font-weight: bold;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

nav a {
    border-radius: 10%;
    padding: 8px;
    background-color: #cccccc;
    color: #1f3b5a;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 30px;
    transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

nav a:hover {
    font-size: 40px;
    transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

nav img {
    width: 30%;
    border: none;
    transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

nav img:hover {
    width: 40%;
    transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

ul {
    margin: 0;
}

nav li:last-of-type a:hover,
nav li:last-of-type a,
nav li:last-of-type a img {
    font-size:0;
    background:none;
    transition: none;
    width: 30%;
    cursor: default;
}
```

```html
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/400" alt="Canadian Women's Hockey League Logo"></li>
        <li> <a href="index.html" target="_blank">Home</a></li>
        <li> <a href="roster.html" target="_blank">Roster</a></li>
        <li> <a href="schedule.html" target="_blank">Schedule</a></li>
        <li>
            <a href="http://cwhl.ca" target="_blank"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/400"></a>
        </li>

    </ul>
</nav>
```